# Are any other distrons which will work on UEFI & Intel Atom CPU (instead of Lubutnu)?

Tags: lubuntu, uefi, debian

Hej, I am looking for **very lightweight ** linux distro to set up on a little trashy notebook. Im gonna using this gear to learnigng and playing with server software, like apache http server, nginx, maybe some ftp servers etc.

I have here Lubuntu now, but I feel the need to check something other. Is is possible to run CentOS, or (please god) Debian on this wicked configuiration? I remaind that is some troubles with OS correct work on this set-up, but I believe that Lubuntu is not my only options.

PS: I dont' care about corrent working sound, network (I some extnal sticks). Please, guide me to uncovered Linux land on my future server

Comment: We only support Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu here sorry - https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: if you have Lubuntu installed (you didn't provide any specifics, particularly release information), why not build what you want out of that. Don't use the default desktop (I don't know what that is given you provided no details) and login via `openbox`, or add another lighter WM (window manager) yourself to use that. You can 'trim' your system down anyway (release info is required here!) to make it lighter; though there are consequences as you trim that must be considered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are looking for something very lightweight (in terms of resource-usage), I can recommend **antiX Linux** to you.

Reasons:

- It is based on Debian
- It supports Debian packages
- It uses XFCE DE, which causes little to nearly no intense resource-usage

Also the well known distro **MX Linux** is based on antiX.

Here is a link to the official website: https://antixlinux.com/

Comment: Are you sure that this distro is compatible with EUEFI and Atom proccessors family?

Comment: @TravelerVihaan Unfortunately, I could not find any pieces of information regarding the UEFI part. However, on the CPU side of things, antiX should run without any issues. I would recommend trying it out on a live USB before installing, since the image is only ~500MB in size. I hope this helps.

Comment: Antix (Icewm/Rox)  is fine on UEFI machines.  I chose it for upgrading the Ubuntu 14.04 installed on the 1GB memory Intel Compute Stick.  Debian works too, but takes more memory with the default settings.

Comment: I don't see this as on-topic, https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic